# Connect combobox to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am new to VBA and I am trying to write a simple code that reads a particular file in my local folder. The code i wrote is:

```
  Sub Opentrading()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim nyear As String
    Dim nmont As String
    Dim nday As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook

    FolderPath = "F:\FICM\Trading Runs\Daily Trading Runs"
    nyear = Sheet6.Range("B2")
    nmont = Sheet6.Range("B3")
    nday = Sheet6.Range("B4")
    Path = FolderPath & "\" & nyear & "-" & nmont & "-" & nday & " Trading - Southern_Europe" & ".xlsx"
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    wkbk.Close savechanges:=False
  End Sub
```

My files are divided by year month and day. So for example i have one file that is "2018-06-12 Trading - Southern_Europe". Now, If i put the exact number in the ranges B2 B3 and B4 the code works, but i need to put a combobox so i can select between years, months and days. How can i do that? I was able to prepare the combobox with 5 years, 12 months and 31 days, but i do not know how to connect to my vba code. I suppose that the range property is no more useful since, while I have positioned the combo boxes in those ranges (B2 B3 and B4) the value is empty, since the actual value is inside the combo box.

Comment: I assume you got your 5yyears, 10months and 31 days comboboxes set up using the Input Range. try to use a Cell Link and then Index formula in another cell to get a value of what was selected in the combox.

Comment: it's a workaround, but it works :D